# Public folders remove all permissions for all users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have hundreds of Public folders, and I need to remove all existing user permissions on each folder, then add new permissions for Default and Anonymous.  Some users don't exist, or are disabled.

This is the ps1 file I've written:

```
param (
  [string] $pf='\Clients'
)
$children = Get-PublicFolder -Identity $pf –Recurse
$children | % {
  $Perm = Get-PublicFolderClientPermission $_.Identity
  $Perm | % {
    Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User $_.User -Confirm:$false
  }
  Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User Default -Confirm:$false
  Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User Default -AccessRights Owner
  Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User Anonymous -Confirm:$false
  Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User Anonymous -AccessRights Contributor
}
```

Error is:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'User'. Cannot convert value
"Default" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderUserIdParameter".
Error: "Cannot convert hashtable to an object of the following type:
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderUserIdParameter.
Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or a
Data section."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

This error is for "Default", same thing happened for normal user accounts that exist.

`$_.User` on the 8th line doesn't parse as a user.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `$_.User` to `$_.User.DisplayName`

I know it was published a long time ago, but it is still relevant.

Same solution :

```
    $a= Get-publicFolder \ -recurse -resultsize unlimited 
    $b= $a | Get-PublicFolderClientPermission
    foreach ($pfper in $b) {
    write-host $pfper.User.DisplayName $pfper.Identity ;  Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission $pfper.Identity -User $pfper.User.DisplayName -Confirm:$false}
    Get-PublicFolder \ -Recurse | Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -User Anonymous -AccessRights None
    Get-PublicFolder \ -Recurse | Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -User Default -AccessRights None
```

Comment: Thx for responding. This doesn't work for deleted users

There is no existing permission entry found for user: FirstName LastName.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-PublicFolderClientPermission], UserNotFoundInPermissionEntryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=SG2PR01MB2093,RequestId=9ba3662f-d53a-464e-96f9-f3cc2a9c0ba5,TimeStamp=29/7/2019 1:40:14 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-UserNotFoundInPer 
   missionEntryException] E7D8880C,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.RemovePublicFolderClientPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com